# Playing multiple sounds using muliple buttons

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

How to make multiple buttons play different sounds one at a time and have a common stop button using Windows Phone XNA framework? When a sound is played, it should play looped until one hits the stop button or hits another button.

The way I used `SoundEffect` with `CreateInstance`, it looped and played fine but when a second button is clicked, the second sound starts playing along with the first. Also need help with creating the common stop button. Thanks a lot in advance.

I was trying something like below for each button.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Sounds/A3.wav");
    var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
    SoundEffectInstance instance = effect.CreateInstance();
    instance.IsLooped = true;
    instance.Play();
```

But since the instance created isn't on a program-wide level, I'm having trouble creating a common stop button.

I'm a beginner in programming. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: Can you show an example of your code so we can see what your trying?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a member variable to your class and some helper methods:

```
public class YourClass
{
    private SoundEffectInstance currentSoundEffect = null;

    private void StopCurrentSoundEffect()
    {
        this.currentSoundEffect.Stop();
        this.currentSoundEffect = null;
    }

    private void PlaySoundEffect(string fileName)
    {
        this.StopCurrentSoundEffect();
        using (var stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Sounds/A3.wav"))
        {
            var soundEffect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream);
            this.currentSoundEffect = soundEffect.CreateInstance();
            this.currentSoundEffect.IsLooped = true;
            this.currentSoundEffect.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, each of your event handlers can just call `this.PlaySoundEffect` with the desired file name.